# Looking for the proper word in a sentence about exams

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I'm trying to find the proper word, but there are a lot of options and I don't know which one fits best.

> I studied this material last night and it ___ on the exam.

I'm thinking of the below words, but I'm not sure which to choose. Or are none of them correct?

- appeared
- came out
- showed up
- arose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them could be used, but I believe the most natural way to write the sentence would be:

- I studied this material last night and it **was** on the exam.